# Persistant android notification, disappears after closing application

Tags: android, notifications

My android notification disappears after closing my app :/ Why? I want to create a persistant notification that will disappear after clicking on it, not after closing the application that creates this notification. Someone can help?

MainActivity class:

```
private void createNotification() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, eTutorActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("xxx")
            .setContentText("xxx")
            .setTicker("xxx")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

MainActivity class onCreate action:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
..
createNotification()
..
}
```

**EDIT:**

Nexus 7 Android 5.1 is working correctly

Nexus 5 Android 6.0.1 is working correctly too

Xioami Redmi Note 2 Android 5.0.2 with MIUI 7.3.2.0 is NOT working and notification disappears after killing application.

Comment: which device are you using and are you removing app from recent list ?

Comment: What is triggering the notification? A service?

Comment: Xiaomi Redmi Note2, notifications from others apps work correctly.
Yes, I am removing app from recent list.
I was trying via service, now I am triggering the notification inside my main (and only) activity in onCreate() method. The result in both cases is the same, the notification is visible until I close (remove from list) the application.

Comment: i am facing this issue also.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but have noticed it only happens when launching the app from android studio.  If I launch it on the phone manually, it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

hope it helps!!!

Comment: It's not working, after removing application from recent list the notification disappears.